# fixed footer with min-width, need to be able to scroll

Tags: jquery, css

I have a footer with the following styling rules:

```
#footer
{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width:1300px;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

I have this JQuery code to make scrolling available only for the x-axis:

```
$('html, body').css({
'overflow-y': 'hidden',
'height': '100%'});
```

When the window is smaller than 1300px, and the scroll bar shows up, how can I make it scroll left and right?

Comment: Put your code in jsFiddle :)

Comment: Couldn't you use position absolute instead?

Comment: thing is that when i use absolute positioning, it kicks the footer way off the page (very low and not accessible because there isnt any scrolling up and down allowed), I can only access the footer then by making the window bigger. Its a design flaw that I am trying to fix...

Comment: So provide a jsfiddle to reproduce your issue. But using position absolute, there is no reason (as i'm aware of) than the footer go out of the page

Comment: well its because the elements above it are pushing it way too far down as they have fixed heights and stuff... i think... im looking into it now..

Comment: @Moose you are speaking about posisiton absolute right? Not position static or relative?! Because position absolute should not give you this kind of result at all, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/RK6kk/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make my comments as an answer, use position absolute as position fixed cannot be scrolled (because element is fixed...)

BTW, as you are setting `overflow-y: hidden` for the body, there is no reason the position absolute should have different behaviour than if using position fixed.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RK6kk/5/)

```
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    min-width:1300px;
    z-index: 3;
    background: red;
    height:60px;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: Deleting my answer and upvoting yours.

Comment: @dwreck08 don't delete your answer, a +1 is waiting for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

How's this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('#footer').css('left',-$(window).scrollLeft());
});
```

You'd also need this (Probably):

```
html, body {
    min-width: 1300px;
}
```

That's the best you'll get from a fixed footer imo